# How many people died in wars caused by Darth Sidious?

Tags: star-wars, darth-sidious

How many people died in all of the wars caused by Darth Sidious?

[image]

Let's count deaths from when Sheev Palpatine begins training as dark side user to when the rebellion establishes the New Republic after his death. Let's count only the wars where he is either an instigator or the leader of a major faction in the war.

I will vote for an answer supported by canon sources.

Comment: Lots. And lots and lots.

Comment: He also had billions killed in "Operation Cinder"; *Cinder had been a turning point. Loyal soldiers who had executed whole planets at the Emperor’s behest had seen billions of lives snuffed out for no strategic gain and known that the moral calculus had changed.* - **Alphabet Squadron**

Comment: The scope of this is beyond any reasonable answer, since you are simply asking how many died. You did not ask how many he killed, or died by his legions, your question covers every person on every side including his own forces, and even accidents and old age. Try to focus the scope

Answer (score 4):

### "Billions"

> The Separatist Supreme Commander is an abomination of nature, a fusion
> of flesh and droid-and his droid parts have more compassion than what
> remains of his alien flesh. **This half-living creature is a slaughterer
> of billions. Whole planets have burned at his command.** He is the evil
> genius of the Confederacy. The architect of their victories.
>
> <sub><sup>[Revenge of the Sith: Official Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_III_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novelization))</sup></sub>

and

> The first is an irresistible bait. **The commanding general of an outlaw nation, personally responsible for billions of deaths across the galaxy, is ideal.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Revenge of the Sith: Official Novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Star_Wars:_Episode_III_Revenge_of_the_Sith_(novelization))</sup></sub>

and

> But you do need to remember where the Empire came from—it rose from
> the ashes of a government that was so consumed by conflict and
> jealousy and greed that it couldn’t function, and from **a terrible war
> in which billions died.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Servants of the Empire: Edge of the Galaxy](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Servants_of_the_Empire%3A_Edge_of_the_Galaxy)</sup></sub>

Comment: I don't think we're going to be able to give a more precise figure than this.